# Make another Fragment appear after ListItem touch event

Tags: android

I'm having a `ListView` that is contained inside a `FrameLayout` gets displayed. What I'd like to do is move a Fragment from the bottom to the list item that has been touched.

As a first iteration I'd be glad to know how to draw one Fragment over another and how to move it..

Comment: I'm sorry to say that but i think you're asking the wrong questions. ListView is deprecated, please look at RecyclerView. As for the remainder of the question - i'm having trouble understanding what it is that you're trying to achieve, please try rephrasing or maybe elaborating a bit more

Comment: @royiby Really? Android Studio does not annotate it as deprecated ... nothing to rely on ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like what you need, this is my previous project.

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
<!-- this frame is invisible -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragInvi"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#253">
</FrameLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

And onItemClickListener:

```
if (fragInvi.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        fragInvi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fragInvi.animate().translationY(-fragInvi.getHeight()).setDuration(500);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Where are you doing that? The onClickListener part. is that in your Fragment?

Comment: I wrote onItemClickListener --> it is part of ListView

Comment: Hmm... I got the code running but it's not doing anything. Is it supposed to appear and then move from the top to the bottom?

Comment: You can download and try it: https://mega.co.nz/#!M41kwT7B!Uz9v5nJZHlYIIUgrMuJD1868Avrh1qr50fyl3FzB2Gc

Comment: In this demo, you must click on Button to see what happen.